# How can I fix a kid thinking I'm its dad when I'm a girl?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-comes-alive

The baby thinks that I'm its dad, but I'm a girl. It keeps calling me dad. I did this for a challenge and I want to fix it. How do I change it to know I'm a girl?

Comment: That title though

Comment: What version of Minecraft?

Comment: It's probably just a bug. I don't really know of a way to fix once it's started.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's not possible without editing the game files (hardcore difficulty)... or killing your insolent child and starting again (beginner difficulty).

If I understand the mechanics correctly, if both parents are the same sex, the player will be chosen as the parent of the missing sex (needs confirmation).